# React Native Promises and componentDidMount behavior with component variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, promise

In a long chain of promises within componentDidMount, I eventually set an array made in the constructor (called this.recentCards) to hold some data retrieved from a firebase query. Afterwards, I set a "loading" state to false so that my render function can properly render the data after it has properly loaded.

However, no data is rendered, and I can see that during the render function, in the branch where "this.state.loading" is false, that this.recentCards is empty. This doesn't make sense as this.recentCards is NOT empty before the loading state is set to false. Does anyone have any idea on how this interaction is occurring? I cannot find any leads.

Here is some code for reference: NOTE: the "that" in that.setState is used as I was having trouble accessing the function this.setState and used 'that' as a variable holding 'this'

```
Promise.all(promises).then(function(results){     
     for(var i = 0; i < tagInfo.length; i++){
     tempArray.push(
     <FeedCard key = {(i + 1) * -1}
        handleToUpdate = {this.addView}
        mutual = {false}
        time = {tagInfo[i]["Time"]}
        restaurantid = {tagInfo[i]["Restaurant"]}
        isRestaurant = {tagInfo[i]["isRestaurant"]}
        dishid = {tagInfo[i]["Dish"]}
        userid = {tagInfo[i]["Author"]}/>
                );
              }
              this.recentCards = tempArray;
              that.setState({loading:false});
```

calling

```
 console.log(this.recentCards)
```

right before the setState shows items in the array.

But, calling it during this function returns no items: And this function is only called once loading is set to false.

```
showCards = () =>{
    console.log(this.recentCards);
    console.log(this.state.loading);
    if(this.state.empty == true){
      return(
        <View style = {{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', backgroundColor:'#F7F6F4'}}>
          <Text>{"No tag activity yet! You can start tagging on the Discover page!"}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
    else{
      return(
        <View style = {styles.contentContainer}>
          {this.recentCards}
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not change the `{this.recentCards}`to `this.state.recentCards`. The value of this.recentCards will never be 'refreshed' so it will only take the initial value.

in your constructor :

```
this.state = {
 ..// state items
 recentCards : <some initial value>
}
```

in your function :

```
Promise.all(promises).then(function(results){     
 for(var i = 0; i < tagInfo.length; i++){
 tempArray.push(
 <FeedCard key = {(i + 1) * -1}
    handleToUpdate = {this.addView}
    mutual = {false}
    time = {tagInfo[i]["Time"]}
    restaurantid = {tagInfo[i]["Restaurant"]}
    isRestaurant = {tagInfo[i]["isRestaurant"]}
    dishid = {tagInfo[i]["Dish"]}
    userid = {tagInfo[i]["Author"]}/>
            );
          }
    that.setState({loading:false, recentCards : tempArray});
```

in your render:

```
showCards = () =>{
console.log(this.recentCards);
console.log(this.state.loading);
if(this.state.empty == true){
  return(
    <View style = {{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', backgroundColor:'#F7F6F4'}}>
      <Text>{"No tag activity yet! You can start tagging on the Discover page!"}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
else{
  return(
    <View style = {styles.contentContainer}>
      {this.state.recentCards}
    </View>
  );
}
```

}